# Python/ Pandas CSV Parsing For Form Responses

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, parsing

I used JotForm Configurable list widget to collect data, but having troubles pwhile parsing or reading the data as the number of records > 2K

The configurable field name is Person Details and the list has these options to take as input,

`Name    Gender  Date of Birth   Govt. ID    Covid Test  Covid Result    Type of Follow Up   Qualification   Medical History Disabilities    Employment Status   Individual Requirement`

A Snap of the excel file, [Configurable List Submissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Ssy.png)

I want the excel or csv sheet having the data as one column as per the snap be exported into different columns with the list options mentioned above as the heading for each column

I'm very much new to python, pandas or data parsing, and this is for a very important and social benefit project to help people during this time of **COVID Crisis** , so any help would be gladly appreciated :)

Comment: You could use panda's [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) or [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel)

Answer (score 0):

This having the labels in each row isn't something the standard pandas tools like `read_csv` handle natively. I would iterate through the rows as text strings, and then build the dataframe one row at a time. We will do this by getting each line into the form `pd.Series({"Column1": "data", "Column2": "data"...})`, and then building a dataframe out of a list of those objects.

```
import pandas as pd
##Sample Data
data = ["Column1: Data1, Column2: Data2, Column3: Data3", "Column1: Data4, Column2: Data5, Column3: Data6"]

rows = []
##Iterate over rows
for line in data:
    ##split along commas
    split1 = line.split(',')
    ##
    split2 = [s.split(': ') for s in split1]
```

Now `split2` for a row looks like this: `[['Column1', ' Data1'], [' Column2', ' Data2'], [' Column3', ' data3']]`

```
    ##make a series
    row = pd.Series({item[0]: item[1] for item in split2})
    rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Now `df` looks like this:

```
  Column1  Column2  Column3
0   Data1    Data2    Data3
1   Data4    Data5    Data6
```

and you can save it in this format with `df.to_csv("filename.csv")` and open it in tools like excel.

Comment: Thank You Jacob!
Will try this and give you can update :)